# How to enable autoescape globally in twig.js?

Tags: node.js, express, twig

I'm using `express.js` and `twig.js` 0.9.5 and I'd like to enable autoescape for all the variables in every template. I've found [this](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js/issues/219) page telling that it should be enabled by default by 0.9.0, but it doesn't seem to work. How do I configure twig to escape everything unless specified otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Express.js` passes whatever is in `twig options` setting to twig, so to enable autoescape for all views, use:

```
var app = express();
app.set('twig options', {
  autoescape: true
});
```

Comment: can you include a resource to where you got this from?